How to squish the vim status bar differently when resizing the terminal window?
So what I want to do is something a little bit tough to explain, so bear with me...
I have made a custom Vim status line. I know Airline and Powerline exist, but this is more of a personal endeavor to learn more about "Vimscripting" and how exactly the status line works.
Normally, when I resize the terminal emulator horizontally, the segments of the status bar are "squished" a certain way, such as getting squished from the left, which is where I put the filename, modify/read-only flags, file format, and file type. What I would like to do is somehow control how these elements get squished. I would like the elements on the right to get "squished" or cut off instead. I will attach some images, because I think visual reference here is key to help others understand what I want...



When resizing a window like this (for example for a vertically-aligned monitor or portrait mode screen), I want the filename to always be visible, and I want the dec/hex values to be squished instead. Mostly, everything on the right should be squished, not on the left. Is there a way to do this?
Here's the portion of code in my Vimrc that does all of this:
""" Status Line with Ruler

if has('statusline') && &t_Co > 2 || has('gui_running')

    " Define the ruler (only shows up when the status line is disabled)
    " Ruler contents: byte, line, lines selected, column
    "                 page number, words, and percentage
    let &rulerformat="%100(%=%*%)" " Set ruler width to 100 characters
    let &rulerformat.=" Byte %o/%{getfsize(expand(@%))},"
    let &rulerformat.=" Line %{line('v')}-%{line('.')}/%L,"
    let &rulerformat.=" L.Sel. %{abs(line('.') - line('v')) + 1},"
    let &rulerformat.=" Col %c%V,"
    let &rulerformat.=" Pg %(%{winheight(0) ? line('.') / winheight(0) + 1 : 0}%)"
    let &rulerformat.="/%(%{winheight(0) ? line('$') / winheight(0) + 1 : 0}%),"
    let &rulerformat.=" %{wordcount().words} Words"
    let &rulerformat.=" %5.P"
    let &rulerformat.=" %*"

    " Define the statusline
    func s:StatusLine()
        " Clear current status line
        set statusline=

        " Set color to User1, add full file path with optional flags.
        " An arbitrary length of 65 characters for the filename is good
        " enough. Most filesystem filenames support 255 ASCII characters.
        " Note that technically the filename includes the file extension string.
        " The part `%(%m%r%)` takes up an extra 0-7 characters.
        " The segment totals 65-72 characters (67-74 with spacers included).
        let &statusline.="%1*"
        let &statusline.=" %<%.65t%(%m%r%)"
        let &statusline.=" %*"

        " Set color to User2, add file format, then file encoding
        " (String length analysis WIP)
        let &statusline.="%2*"
        let &statusline.=" %{&ff} > %{strlen(&fenc) ? &fenc : '(none)'}"
        let &statusline.=" %*"

        " Set color to User3, add file type if available
        " Bacause the longest filetype name is `upstreaminstalllog`, it seems
        " like the string limit and segment length should be 20 characters
        " (22 with spacers included).
        let &statusline.="%3*"
        let &statusline.=" %.20{&filetype}"
        let &statusline.=" %*"

        " Set color to Default, add dec, hex and octal of selected character
        " Note that U+10FFFF (or dec 1114111) is the maximum range of Unicode.
        " And for octal it is 4177777. Those measure 34 fixed characters long.
        " With octal off, it measures 22 fixed characters long.
        " Total segment length is either 34 or 56 fixed characters long.
        " (36 or 58 with spacers included).
        let &statusline.="%*"
        let &statusline.=" d=%-7b"
        let &statusline.=" ┃"
        let &statusline.=" h=%-6B"
        "let &statusline.=" ┃"
        "let &statusline.=" o=%{printf('%-7o', char2nr(getline('.')[col('.') - 1]))}"
        let &statusline.=" %*"

        " Set color to User4, add show keymap
        let &statusline.="%4*"
        let &statusline.=" <%k>"
        let &statusline.=" %*"

        " Separation point for right aligned items (using user3 colors)
        let &statusline.="%*%="

        " Add the ruler to the status bar when the ruler is enabled
        if &ruler
            let &statusline.=&rulerformat
        endif
    endfunc

    " Initialize the status line
    call s:StatusLine()

    " Update the statusline when the ruler variable is toggled
    if has('autocmd')
        autocmd OptionSet ruler call s:StatusLine()
    endif
endif

And don't get me started with setting up the ruler! I already know the Vim status line cannot be two lines long, but honestly, I might just have the ruler be separate or something, or disable it entirely and use Ctrl-G. I dunno just yet. But anyway, that's not part of the question... Anyone know what to do here?

Okay, I solved it. I needed to get rid of the "%<" in the first part of the status line with the file path, and instead add it for the dec/hex readout. I just forgot how to do it...
let &statusline.="%*"
let &statusline.="%<" " Truncate statusbar lines here.
let &statusline.=" d=%-7b"
let &statusline.=" ┃"
let &statusline.=" h=%-6B"
"let &statusline.=" ┃"
"let &statusline.=" o=%{printf('%-7o', char2nr(getline('.')[col('.') - 1]))}"
let &statusline.=" %*"

